# How to replace vacant pixels of texture2D after offsetting from original vec4?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, textures, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Basically I'm offsetting a texture2D from its original inputImageTexture with this code

```
highp vec2 toprightcoord = textureCoordinate + 0.25;
highp vec4 tr = texture2D(inputImageTexture, toprightcoord);
```

It's does what it supposed to do, however it leaves a stretched pixel color from the edge of the offsetted texture (like a cheese from pulled pizza slice).
How to replace it to any color or transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have set the texture wrap parameters to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).
This causes the stretched pixels when access the texture with the texture lookup function `texture2D`, out of the range [0.0, 1.0].

You can create a "tiled" texture with the wrap parameter `GL_REPEAT`.

But if you want

> "How to replace it to any color or transparent?"

, then you have to do a range check.

The following code sets the alpha channel to 0.0, if the limit of 1.0 is exceeded at either the `x` or `y` coordinate. Where the variable `inBounds` is set to 1.0 if the texture coordinate is in bounds and else it is set to 0.0:

```
vec2 toprightcoord = textureCoordinate + 0.25;
vec4 tr = texture2D(inputImageTexture, toprightcoord);

vec2  boundsTest = step(toprightcoord, vec2(1.0));
flaot inBounds   = boundsTest.x * boundsTest.y;
tr.a *= inBounds;
```

You can extend this, to a range test in [0.0, 1.0]:

```
vec2 boundsTest = step(vec2(0.0), toprightcoord) * step(toprightcoord, vec2(1.0));
```

Note, the glsl function [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/step.xml)

```
genType step( genType edge, genType x);
```

returnes 0.0, if `x[i] < edge[i]`, and 1.0 is returned otherwise.

With the glsl function [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/mix.xhtml), the color can be replaced by a different one:

```
vec4 red = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
tr = mix(red, tr, inBounds);
```

Comment: awesome, this works, although the transparent part still leaves some mixed color it still does what it should. thanks man